# Is Object.assign() better than create an object with variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, object, dom, javascript-objects, appendchild

I'm learning Javascript and just started the DOM class, from the start I've been unconfortable with creating elements by variable declarations because it looked so massive, after some research I've found the Object.assign. After some thougths and tests I've came to the following thoughts, but since I'm new to this I'd like to be sure that I'm not missing something important.

When a node is **created using variable declaration**, in order to create a new node of same HTML tag is **required to declare a new variable** because if you *append()*, or *appendChild()*, the **same variable** you'll move it instead of creating a new one.

```
const p = document.createElement("p")
p.textContent = "<p> Text </p>"
document.body.appendChild(p)

const p1 = document.createElement("p")
p1.id = "p1"
p1.textContent = `<p id="p1">P1 Text</p>`
document.body.appendChild(p1)

const paragraph = document.createElement("p")
paragraph.className = "paragraph"
paragraph.textContent = `<p class="paragraph">Paragraph Text</p>`
document.body.appendChild(paragraph)

document.body.appendChild(p)
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrdsantos/pen/rNKJdQv)

Node.cloneNode(), -at moment-, doesnt solve this problem because it will result in a new element with same attributes, same ID's for exemple, creating a mess.

---

When a node is created using Object.assing() function you dont need to declare a variable for it, neither you need to create new variables for other nodes of same HTML tag because the object is created from scratch. This gives you the freedom to assign new properties freely without risk to mess up what you already done.

```
document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("p"),
        {textContent: `<p>Text<p>`}))

document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("p"),
        {id: "p1"},
        {textContent: '<p id="p1">Text</p>'}))

document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("p"),
        {className: "paragraph"},
        {textContent: `<p class="paragraph">Text</p>`}))

document.body.appendChild(
    Object.assign(
        document.createElement("p"),
        {textContent: `new <p>Text<p>`}))
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrdsantos/pen/vYrdRRq)

Comment: I've never seen it done that way (using `Object.assign()`) but it seems reasonable to me... though personally I prefer creating an html string (instead of `document.createElement('p')`). Something like `document.body.innerHTML += '<p id="p1">Text</p>';`. That way creating elements in javascript and creating elements in html are both expressed in the same way (less to learn/remember that way).

Comment: I see, I'm trying to stay away from the innerHTML after reading about some problems that may occur, maybe I'm overdoing it though.